# How to update only modified properties of an entity when an unmodified property is marked as required

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have the following entity

```
public class City()
{  
  [Key]
  public int Id {get; set;}
  [Required]
  public int RegionId {get; set;}
  public string City {get; set;}
}
```

I work with a disconnected context and when I update City, only the values for Id and City will be set, **RegionId will be null**.

```
public void updateCity(int id, string City)
{
    var c = new City();
    c.Id = id;
    c.City = City;

    using (var db = new MyContext())
    {
      db.Cities.Attach(c);
      db.Entry(c).Property(a => a.RegionId).IsModified = false;
      db.SaveChanges();
     }
```

db.SaveChanges() throws an exception, telling me

> RegionId is required.

Is there a way to tell EF to create an update-Statement without using RegionId?

Regardsa
M :)

Answer (score 0):

You could fetch old item from DB and update your modified properties.

```
var cityToUpdate=db.Cities.Find(id);
cityToUpdate.City=City;
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Hi Sam,I tried this but it seems not very elegant to me, because you have an extra call to the database. :-/ I like to avoid this rountrip to the database. If I create a SQL-Statement s.th. like `update City set City = paramCity Where Id = paramId ` would be the solution.